# Drag and drop + snapping hexagonal Trello-like cards

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am totally stuck with a school project where we are to code a kanban style webapp. I wanted to be able to generate hexagonal cards with some options in them and be able to drag and snap them togheter in a honeycomb fashion as you put them togheter. I've tried different thing and I am stuck so I was looking for some tips or if someone is able to help me on the way.

I've tried a few things including this last solution involving JavaScript and some JQuery, but the hexagons make the snapping very inacurate. Also if would be nice to avoid any libraries, but that's not mandatory.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div id="hex" data-x="20" data-y="20" class="hexagon draggable ui-widget-content"></div>
        <div id="hex" data-x="50" data-y="50" class="hexagon draggable ui-widget-content"></div>
        <div id="hex" data-x="50" data-y="50" class="hexagon draggable ui-widget-content"></div>
        <div id="hex" data-x="50" data-y="50" class="hexagon draggable ui-widget-content"></div>
        <div id="hex" data-x="50" data-y="50" class="hexagon draggable ui-widget-content"></div>

</div>

<div>
  <p id="position">
    Position
  </p>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs/dist/interact.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px; 
  height: 86.60px;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  margin: 43.30px 0;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 43.30px solid #64C7CC;
}

.hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 43.30px solid #64C7CC;
}

.ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px solid #64C7CC;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  color: #222222;
}

.container {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 900px;
}
```

```
var AXIS_RANGE = 12;
var CORNER_RANGE = 14;
var CORNER_EXCLUDE_AXIS = 8;
var AXIS_EXTRA_RANGE = -6;

var myItems = [];
var currentElement = null;
var offX1, offY1, offX2, offY2;

function getPosition(element) {
  return {
    x: parseFloat(element.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0,
    y: parseFloat(element.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0
  };
}

function isBetween(value, min, length) {
  return min - AXIS_EXTRA_RANGE < value && value < (min + length) + AXIS_EXTRA_RANGE;
}

function getDistance(value1, value2) {
  return Math.abs(value1 - value2);
}

function getSnapCoords(element, axis) {
  var result = {
    isOK: false
  };
  if (currentElement && currentElement !== element) {
    var pos = getPosition(element);
    var cur = getPosition(currentElement);
    var distX1a = getDistance(pos.x, cur.x);
    var distX1b = getDistance(pos.x, cur.x + currentElement.offsetWidth);
    var distX2a = getDistance(pos.x + element.offsetWidth, cur.x);
    var distX2b = getDistance(pos.x + element.offsetWidth, cur.x + currentElement.offsetWidth);
    var distY1a = getDistance(pos.y, cur.y);
    var distY1b = getDistance(pos.y, cur.y + currentElement.offsetHeight);
    var distY2a = getDistance(pos.y + element.offsetHeight, cur.y);
    var distY2b = getDistance(pos.y + element.offsetHeight, cur.y + currentElement.offsetHeight);
    var distXa = Math.min(distX1a, distX2a);
    var distXb = Math.min(distX1b, distX2b);
    var distYa = Math.min(distY1a, distY2a);
    var distYb = Math.min(distY1b, distY2b);
    if (distXa < distXb) {
      result.offX = offX1;
    } else {
      result.offX = offX2
    }
    if (distYa < distYb) {
      result.offY = offY1;
    } else {
      result.offY = offY2
    }
    var distX1 = Math.min(distX1a, distX1b);
    var distX2 = Math.min(distX2a, distX2b);
    var distY1 = Math.min(distY1a, distY1b);
    var distY2 = Math.min(distY2a, distY2b);
    var distX = Math.min(distX1, distX2);
    var distY = Math.min(distY1, distY2);
    var dist = Math.max(distX, distY);
    var acceptAxis = dist > CORNER_EXCLUDE_AXIS;

    result.x = distX1 < distX2 ? pos.x : pos.x + element.offsetWidth;
    result.y = distY1 < distY2 ? pos.y : pos.y + element.offsetHeight;

    var inRangeX1 = isBetween(pos.x, cur.x, currentElement.offsetWidth);
    var inRangeX2 = isBetween(cur.x, pos.x, element.offsetWidth);
    var inRangeY1 = isBetween(pos.y, cur.y, currentElement.offsetHeight);
    var inRangeY2 = isBetween(cur.y, pos.y, element.offsetHeight);

    switch (axis) {
      case "x":
        result.isOK = acceptAxis && (inRangeY1 || inRangeY2);
        break;
      case "y":
        result.isOK = acceptAxis && (inRangeX1 || inRangeX2);
        break;
      default:
        result.isOK = true;
        break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

$('.draggable').each(function() {
  var pos = getPosition(this);
  this.style.transform = 'translate(' + pos.x + 'px, ' + pos.y + 'px)';
  myItems.push(getPosition(this));
});

interact('.draggable').draggable({
  onstart: function(event) {
    currentElement = event.target;
    var pos = getPosition(currentElement);
    offX1 = event.clientX - pos.x;
    offY1 = event.clientY - pos.y;
    offX2 = event.clientX - currentElement.offsetWidth - pos.x;
    offY2 = event.clientY - currentElement.offsetHeight - pos.y;
  },
  onmove: dragMoveListener,
  snap: {
    targets:
      (function() {
        var snapPoints = [];
        $('.draggable').each(function() {
          (function(element) {
            // Slide along the X axis
            snapPoints.push(
              function(x, y) {
                var data = getSnapCoords(element, "x");
                if (data.isOK) {
                  return {
                    x: data.x + data.offX,
                    range: AXIS_RANGE
                  };
                }
              });
            // Slide along the Y axis
            snapPoints.push(
              function(x, y) {
                var data = getSnapCoords(element, "y");
                if (data.isOK) {
                  return {
                    y: data.y + data.offY,
                    range: AXIS_RANGE
                  };
                }
              });
            // Snap to corner
            snapPoints.push(
              function(x, y) {
                var data = getSnapCoords(element);
                if (data.isOK) {
                  return {
                    x: data.x + data.offX,
                    y: data.y + data.offY,
                    range: CORNER_RANGE
                  };
                }
              });
          })(this);
        });
        return snapPoints;
      })()
  },
  onend: function(event) {
    $('.draggable').each(function() {
      currentElement = null;
      myItems.push(getPosition(this));
    });
  }
});

function dragMoveListener(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var oldPos = getPosition(target);
  var x = oldPos.x + event.dx;
  var y = oldPos.y + event.dy;

  // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
  target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
  target.setAttribute('data-y', y);

  // translate the element
  target.style.webkitTransform =
    target.style.transform =
    'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

  $('#position').text('x: ' + x + ' - y: ' + y);

  var result = $.grep(myItems, function(e) {
    if (e.x == parseInt(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || e.y == parseInt(target.getAttribute('data-y')))
      return 1;
  });

  if (result.length >= 1)
    target.style.backgroundColor = '#64C7CC';
  else
    target.style.backgroundColor = '#64C7CC';
}
```

So to recap, what I'm trying to achieve is the possibility to generate new hexagonal cards, write a title and comment in them and then be able to drag, drop and make them snap togheter to form a honeycomb structure.

Any help would be SO greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula

Comment: Thanks Chris! That resource helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you would have found a solution by now but just in case anybody else comes along looking for something similar.

jQuery offers many interaction that you can use to do what you want.

Here is an example which uses draggable interaction with snapping suppport:
https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to

And then there is this, if you want sorting plus dragging and between two lists:
https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Those resources are pretty self explanatory and hope if helps.